# check answer from database and then increment score

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jsp

I am working on a project named aptitude test.
There are total 30 questions there, when I click on 1st question's button it shows me the question no 1's description.

now I want that when user type the answer in the text box and when click on submit button then it should me checked the answers from database (my database contains question_no, question, and answer), so that it should check the answer and if it is correct then it should increment the score value.

my code for index file is given below.

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body onload="func();">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="header">
        <h1 align="center">Online Aptitude-2k17</h1></div>
    <table align="center" width="100%">
        <tr id="t1">
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
    function func() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
            var x = document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML;
            var p = "<td><input type='button' value='" + i + "' onclick ='myFunction(" + i + ");'/></td>";
            document.getElementById("t1").innerHTML = x + p;
        }
    }

    function myFunction(a) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "retrieveQuestion.php?question=" + a, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    <div id="ques" style="text-align:center; padding:20px"></div>
    <table align="center" cellspacing="20px">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" name="answer" placeholder="Submit Your Answer Here" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="button" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

    </html>
```

code for retrieve question from database is as follows.

```
<?php
include "DBConnect.php";
$question_no = $_GET["question"];
$sql         = "SELECT Question_No,Question FROM problems WHERE Question_No='$question_no'";
$result      = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Question-";
        echo $row["Question_No"];
        echo "  <br><br>";
        echo $row["Question"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Now I really need your help that what should I change in the above code that solve my problem.
e.g. suppose if I click on question 1 then it shows me question-1 description and then I click on submit after type my answer then it should be check that answer is correct or not from database table.

Please I really need help in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I barely understand your question. Did you ever ask one?

Comment: I am new to stack overflow but yes i had asked almost 7 questions on stack overflow.

Comment: I was not asking if you asked any questions on the site. I was asking what your question is because it is very unclear. If you could tell me, I'll most likely be able to answer your question.

Comment: the answers that you want to get is a number of one of several answers?